# Getting public tweets using C#

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp, twitter-client

```
TwitterService service = new TwitterService();
service.AuthenticateWith("XXXXXX", "XXXXXXX");
// Geting Tweets On Specific Topic
var twts = service.Search("#ghaza", 100);
List<TwitterSearchStatus> resultList = new List<TwitterSearchStatus>(twts.Statuses);
foreach (var twt in resultList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(twt.Text);
}
```

I use this code to get tweets on ghaza
there are two things which i want to know

1. What should i do to get result in `json` form
2. This is giving me some strange output in start
   like:

```
    join karain
     #IRAN
     #IRAQ
     #PAK
     #SHAM
     #GHAZA
```

and after iterating this some time, then it show me the tweets, which i want to get in `json` format

I use this:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} says '{1}'", twt.User.ScreenName, twt.Text);
```

but its not working in it.

Comment: Why are you making 2 instances of `TwitterService`? and calling `AuthenticateWith` on a third one?

Comment: I change it ,but it not solve my problem

Comment: which twitter library is it?

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me

```
TwitterResponse<TwitterSearchResultCollection> tr = TwitterSearch.Search("#christmas");

TwitterSearchResultCollection results = tr.ResponseObject;
List<TwitterSearchResult> resultList = results.ToList();

foreach ( TwitterSearchResult resultRow in resultList ) {
    messages.AppendText( "\n" + resultRow.Text );
}
```

The `TwitterSearchResult` object has the following properties ([found in the documentation](http://www.twitterizer.net/documentation/html/T_Twitterizer_TwitterSearchResult.htm)):

```
CreatedDate
```

Gets or sets the created date.

```
FromUserId
```

Gets or sets from user id.

```
FromUserScreenName
```

Gets or sets the name of from user screen.

```
Geo
```

Gets or sets the geo location associated with the result.

```
Id
```

Gets or sets the status id.

```
Language
```

Gets or sets the language.

```
Location
```

Gets or sets the location.

```
ProfileImageLocation
```

Gets or sets the profile image URL.

```
Source
```

Gets or sets the source.

```
Text
```

Gets or sets the status text.

```
ToUserId
```

Gets or sets to user id.

```
ToUserScreenName
```

Gets or sets the name of to user screen.